# MYSQL Merging tag tables into one

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have tables to organize tags..

3 tables for articles and article tags:

```
article_tags
---
tag_id *
tag_name

articles
---
article_id *
article_name 

individual_article_tags
----
article_id *
tag_id *
```

AND 3 separate tables for images and images tags

```
image_tags
---
tag_id *
tag_name

images
---
image_id *
image_name 

individual_image_tags
----
image_id *
tag_id *
```

I want the articles and images tables to reference Only 1 tag table instead of 2 tag tables like so:

```
tags
---
tag_id *
tag_name

articles
---
article_id *
article_name 

individual_article_tags
----
article_id *
tag_id *

images
---
image_id *
image_name 

individual_image_tags
----
image_id *
tag_id *
```

The problem is that the tags have different IDs and I don't know how to merge them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create an new `tags_unified` table with its own auto_increment id (which will differ from either of the other existing tables) by doing `INSERT INTO ...SELECT` with a `UNION`. The result will be a distinct set of all tags from both tables.

```sql
CREATE TABLE tags_unified (
  tags_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tag_name VARCHAR(64)
);

/* Load up all the tags with new ids */
INSERT INTO tags_unified (tag_name)
  SELECT tag_name FROM article_tags
  UNION
  SELECT tag_name FROM image_tags
```

Then `UPDATE` all the `individual_image_tags` and `inidividual_article_tags` with a `JOIN` query to get the new ids.

```sql
UPDATE
  individual_image_tags
  JOIN image_tags ON individual_image_tags.tag_id = image_tags.tag_id
  /* LEFT JOIN the old tags to the new tags by tag_name */
  LEFT JOIN tags_unified ON image_tags.tag_name = tags_unified.tag_name
SET individual_image_tags.tag_id = tags_unified.tag_id
/* And update those which have a match in the new tags table */
WHERE tags_unified.tag_id IS NOT NULL

UPDATE
  individual_article_tags
  JOIN article_tags ON individual_article_tags.tag_id = article_tags.tag_id
  LEFT JOIN tags_unified ON article_tags.tag_name = tags_unified.tag_name
SET individual_article_tags.tag_id = tags_unified.tag_id
WHERE tags_unified.tag_id IS NOT NULL
```

Before running the `UPDATE` statements, re-form them as `SELECT` statements to verify the results.

```sql
SELECT
  individual_image_tags.*, 
  tags_unified.*
FROM
  individual_image_tags
  JOIN image_tags ON individual_image_tags.tag_id = image_tags.tag_id
  LEFT JOIN tags_unified ON image_tags.tag_name = tags_unified.tag_name
WHERE tags_unified.tag_id IS NOT NULL

SELECT
 individual_article_tags.*, 
 tags_unified.*
FROM
  individual_article_tags
  JOIN article_tags ON individual_article_tags.tag_id = article_tags.tag_id
  LEFT JOIN tags_unified ON article_tags.tag_name = tags_unified.tag_name
WHERE tags_unified.tag_id IS NOT NULL
```

#### Edit:

The `LEFT JOIN` and the `WHERE` clause should not actually be necessary, because the *should* be a match for every existing tag in the `tags_unified` table.

#### Update after comments:

It may be easier to create temporary tables and repopulate the original link tables from those than to drop and re-add unique constraints or composite keys.  Use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS SELECT...`.  Then delete all rows from the original table and use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to re-fill it from the temp table.

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_individual_article_tags AS
    SELECT
     individual_article_tags.article_id 
     tags_unified.tag_id
    FROM
      individual_article_tags
      JOIN article_tags ON individual_article_tags.tag_id = article_tags.tag_id
      LEFT JOIN tags_unified ON article_tags.tag_name = tags_unified.tag_name
    WHERE tags_unified.tag_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I don't understand this part:  "Before running the UPDATE statements, re-form them as SELECT statements to verify the results."

Comment: Just execute the SELECT statements to make sure that the results look like what you expect before doing the UPDATE.

Comment: On the update I got an error: #1062 - Duplicate entry '38-18' for key 'PRIMARY', does that mean statement stopped there, or does it keep going after the duplicate?

Comment: @bushdiver if you have a composite key across both columns you should probably just drop the key, do the update, then add the key back. I _think_ it stops where the error occurs.  Or, it would be easier maybe to use the `SELECT` statements instead of the `UPDATE` and store it in a temporary table. Then delete all rows from the original `inidividual_article_tags` and `individual_image_tags` tables and repopulate them from the temporary tables.

Comment: I dropped the primaries and then re-added them after (was running into temporary duplicates) -  your solution to merge the tables worked beautifully, THANKS!  =]